# Want to Clean Install of LInux

Tags: partitioning

i've an preInstall Windows 8 64bit laptop. and i'm totally getting sick for this windows os only because  even though i've Core i7 with 8 GB DDR3 RAM & 4GB Graphics, it still getting lag.
so now i've decide to switch over Linux aka Ubnutu os.
but right now i've an 1TB HDD with 2 partition C & D drive, while in D drive loaded with IMPORTANT data which i dont want to lose. and in C drive having only Dope Windows OS.
So tell me, How to Install Ubuntu in C drive while without affecting D drive. (NOT Dual Boot).

Answer (score 1):

While installing Ubuntu you need to declare your instructions inside the partitions manager. You have to delete your C partition and install Ubuntu inside the free space on your hard drive. After installing you need to mount D into your file system. Another way to keep your data is to backup them on an external drive and copy them on your computer after installing Ubuntu.
Anyway it is strongly recommended that you copy your data on the D drive to an external disk (usb, CD, etc.). As long as you are new to Linux it is possible that you may confuse some things and erase necessary data.